# only use certain modules from my module_path in vagrant puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet, facter

Not experienced with puppet and vagrant. We used to have all the puppet settings in a big puppet repository and our vagrant instance worked fine. Recently, to have things better isolated so they are not rolled out accidentally, we have a certain path from the big puppet repos separated into a new puppet repos. But I still need all the facters living within the old big repos while the server specific setting from the new repos. Unfortunately, I cannot just specify the big old repos as a module path as my server specific settings will come from the old directory in the old repos, but if I just specify the new repos as the module path, then I miss all the facts. And I have been googling crazily to find a way to specify the facter path for vagrant in vain :(

```
old_repos -> dir -> my_server_setting
             -> module1 -> facter
             -> module2 -> facter
             ....

new_repos -> my_server_setting
```

can anyone please give me some hints? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `module_path` can be a vector

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.module_path = ["old_repos","new_repos"]
    puppet.manifest_file  = "base.pp"
  end
end
```

I never tried but I guess the `hiera_config_path` can specify a vector of location too so if you have hiera defined in both the old and the new repos you should be able to point the 2.

Comment: Thank you, Frederic. Hate to say this. I have tried listing multiple module paths. Still not working. Now I got  could not find class .... But I think I have linked the right directories :(  Can I have some infor on how vagrant loads puppet classes?

Comment: hum .. can you ssh into the VM and make sure the modules are correctly mount as `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0` and `/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-1` ? can you try to run the puppet command directly from the VM using `puppet apply --modulepath <link to oldrepo>:<link to newrepo> manifests/base.pp`